# How to customize the title bar of application?

Tags: android, view

How do you customize the title bar in android. Like adding a back button to it?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the greendroid library, which let's you add buttons to the title bar (among other nice things): http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=240 and https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid
The lib has many other features as well (QuickActionBar). This needs some more work though (subclasses of Activity etc.)